# How can i setOnClickListener in Adapter And access From Fragment?

Tags: android, gridview, fragment, onclicklistener

I am developing an app like google Play Music!
the thing is like that app i have a popupmenu for each row on my gridview.
I'm setting grid view adapter from fragment which implements onClickListener.
question is:
how can i set onclicklistener for each popupmenu and handle onclick event from fragment
my popupmenu contains two items :
DELETE
Add to playList

the reason i want to access onClick from fragment is i want to delete the specific file and update grid view with notifydatasetchanged() !

how can i do this or any suggestion for how can i delete the specific file from adapter n update grid view!

thanks!

this is my GridView Adapter :

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    item = songs.get(position);

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(com.irangrammy.irangrammy.R.layout.mchannel_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.thumbnail = (ImageView) row.findViewById(com.irangrammy.irangrammy.R.id.image);
        holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(com.irangrammy.irangrammy.R.id.singer);
        holder.mMenu = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemOption);

        holder.mMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                PopupMenu popUp = new PopupMenu(context, v);
                MenuInflater inflater = popUp.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.mchannel_popup, popUp.getMenu());
                popUp.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(arg0.getItemId()==R.id.delete)
                        {

                        }
                    return true;
                    }
                });
                popUp.show();       
            }
        });
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: use interface or pass your fragment to Adapter class

Comment: @shayanpourvatan i pass fragment to my adapter class , but it doesn't work! can u give me example how to pass fragment to adapter n retrieve it in adapter class?

Comment: pass your fragment to Adapter class , instead of creating new OnClickListener cast your fragment to onClickListener, i'm not sure about that but you can try that

Comment: @shayanpourvatan i pass fragment which implements onCLickListener by this, n retrieve it in adapter class but get this error when cast it :
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (Fragment)

Comment: cast your fragment to OnClickListener

Comment: @shayanpourvatan how to cast? i use setOnclickListener(myFragment) but get that error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66319/discussion-between-mahdi-giveie-and-shayan-pourvatan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass your fragment to Adapter class and cast your fragment to onClickListener, but be sure that you have implement onClickListener on Fragment class.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't get you! but if I understand you the Solution:
Try think of sending broadcast to your fragment, and when the fragment get the broadcast, deal with it as you want.
UPDATE: if you want to set listener to the view you can do it:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                     // Do what you want when the view clicked!
                    }
                });
```

If this not the answer - send me message with your native language

Comment: thanks , the question is : how can i set o'clock listener for a view from adapter class n listen for it in onClick method at fragment which extends onClickListener!

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding you.

Comment: not a problem , thanks by the way , i solved it by passing fragment

Answer (score 1):

first of all your View holder design pattern is wrong it must be like below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    item = songs.get(position);

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(com.irangrammy.irangrammy.R.layout.mchannel_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.thumbnail = (ImageView) row.findViewById(com.irangrammy.irangrammy.R.id.image);
        holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(com.irangrammy.irangrammy.R.id.singer);
        holder.mMenu = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemOption);


        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

        holder.mMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                PopupMenu popUp = new PopupMenu(context, v);
                MenuInflater inflater = popUp.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.mchannel_popup, popUp.getMenu());
                popUp.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(arg0.getItemId()==R.id.delete)
                        {
                           songs.get(position).remove();
                           notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    return true;
                    }
                });
                popUp.show();       
            }
        });
}
```